# Nonzero-homologous simple loop in Mobius band only winds once

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, curves

I have a question as follows: Let $C$ be a closed curve in the Mobius band without self intersections. Prove that if $C$ is of non-zero homology, i.e., $C$ does not bound any face, then $C$ winds only once around the Mobius band.

The picture is clear, however I do not know how to prove it. Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi \colon M \to S^1$ denote the usual projection and let $C$ denote a non-zero homologous simple closed curve with no self intersections, i.e. an injective map $c$ from $S^1$ to $M$, which induces something non-zero on homology.

We can isotop $c$ s.th. $\pi \circ c$ is a covering of $S^1$ (This is not that hard, you just make the map locally injective by pushing half-circles in).

We think of the Möbius band as a quotient of the square and assume further that $c$ is constant along a neighborhood of $\{1\} \times I$. The number $n$ of preimages of $1$ under $\pi \circ c$ is the absolute value of the degree in this case. 
Let's distinguish two cases: Firstly if $n$ is odd, we can isotop $c$ s.th the middle point in the preimage is exactly $([1],[1/2])$, but this gives us a contradiction if $n \geq 2$, because then it follows that the image is not connected, because there is no arc from the other points in the preimage to $([1],[1/2])$.

If $n$ is even we can isotop $c$ s.th. the outer two points in the preimages differ exactly by $1/2$, and this gives a contradiction if $n \neq 2$ regarding connectedness in a similiar way as the other case, because then there is no arc connecting the outer two points to the other point in the preimage.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure I understand your answer. Let me restate the problem as follows: We have a loop $C$ such that $[C]=1\in H_1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Suppose that $[C]=n\in H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$. Prove that if $C$ has no self intersections, then $n=1$. By your answer, let say $\gamma_1$ is a loop whose homology class generates $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})$, and $\gamma_2$ is the boundary curve of $M$, then  $\gamma_2$ is homologous to $2\gamma_1$ and $C$ is homologous to $n\gamma_1$. We know that all $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ and $C$ have no intersections, but how can we imply that $n=1$?

Comment: Ah ok. This changes everything. I was thinking about  homological self intersections and the fact that this should be a non zero class in integral homology. You should change the question and I will give you an answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks! I think there is a stronger statement as follows: if $C$ is a simple closed curve on the Mobius band, then it winds the Mobius at most twice. In order to prove it, we can look at the lift of $C$ to the cylinder, the double cover of the Mobius band. Note that a simple closed curve on the cylinder can only wind at most once (using mean value theorem), thus we get the result.

Comment: My argument proves your claim. But your argument is much more elegant.